# How do I print the binary representation of the first character in a string

Tags: java

i want to retrieve the binary values of the data in the file. so i have written the following the code:

```
while ((fileData = br.readLine()) != null) {
  byte b[] = fileData.getBytes("UTF-8");
  BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(b);
  String s = bi.toString(2);
  System.out.println("Original message in binary: " + s);
  System.out.println("Original message length: " + s.length());
}
```

output:

```
abca (this is the data in a text file)
Original message in binary: <here>1100001011000100110001101100001
Original message length: 31
```

Everything is fine but while i am printing the data in binary format i am not able to print the first bit (`<here>`) can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For first character:

```
s.charAt(0);
```

---

**EDIT:**
If you want to print the binary representation of first byte then try this:

```
    String str = Integer.toBinaryString("abca".getBytes("UTF-8")[0]);
    System.out.println(str);
```

**EDIT 2:**
Try this for leading zeroes.

```
static String addLeadingZeroes(String s) {
    int zeroes = s.length() % 8;
    byte[] bzero = new byte[8 - zeroes];
    Arrays.fill(bzero, (byte)0x30);
    return new StringBuilder(new String(bzero)).append(s).toString();
}
```

and call as

```
System.out.println("Original message in binary: "+ addLeadingZeroes(s));
```

Comment: thank you. but it is printing an character. but i want it to be printed in binary representation in a string

Comment: @user631785: do you want to print '1' as "0000 0001" or "0011 0000"?

Comment: "0"1100001011000100110001101100001 this is the actual representation of abca but when i am printing with charAt(0) i am getting it as  "1"1100001011000100110001101100001 that is the problem

Comment: note that as per http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29  "This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2) **with no extra leading 0s**"

Comment: `static String addLeadingZeroes(String s) { return "00000000".substring(s.length % 8) + s;}` is a little simpler, imo

Comment: thank you. the code is working. Now what if i need to add "1". And i dont know when i need add 0 or add 1

Comment: Is there any other solution other than adding "0" or "1" to print the first bit

Comment: @user631785: you, always, need zero only. In case of 1, the return string will have it. since leading zeroes are not significant, they are omitted.

Comment: no! i have just tried by printing the | (pipe symbol) in binary even then 1 is omitted in the beginning

Comment: @user631785: Remember, all ascii values are 7 bit values. 8th bit is always zero. ascii value for pipe(|) is 124 which is equivalent to "01111100" in binary

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you're saying is that when the first binary digit is a "0", that it is not displayed.  If you want to insure that you're displaying a full 32 binary digits, you can use the following code.

```
public static final THIRTYTWO_ZEROS = "00000000000000000000000000000000";

String s = bi.toString(2);
s = THIRTYTWO_ZEROS.substring(s.length) + s;
```

This has the effect of padding your string with preceding "0" characters to a length of 32 characters.