# Print in Java Char array as binary

Tags: java, binary, system.out

I've a char array

```
static char[] myArray  ={   
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x48, 0x48, 0x48, 0xb0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x20,
0x20, 0x20, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x40, 0xa0, 0xa0, 0xa0, 0x20, 0x00,
0x00, 0x20, 0xf0, 0x20, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x08, 0xf8, 0x08,
};
```

How could I print it as 8-bit binary ?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917163/convert-a-string-like-testing123-to-binary-in-java

Comment: printing a single char: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381504/how-do-i-print-the-binary-representation-of-the-first-character-in-a-string Adding the loop is straightforward.

Comment: It's not as same as those links, the conversion to binary is the same, but the _8-bit_ part is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `toBinaryString` for each item:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        String b = Integer.toBinaryString(myArray[i]);

        if (b.length() < 8) {
            b = "000000000".substring(0, 8 - b.length()).concat(b);
        } else {
            b = b.substring(b.length() - 8);
        }

        System.out.print(b + " ");
 }
```

Output

> 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   00000000 11111000 01001000 01001000 01001000 1011000 ...

Answer (score 0):

if you output to be `0000000000000000f848484...` then

```
    for(char c : myArray) {
        System.out.printf("%02x", (int)c);
    }
```

Comment: This does not output binary ;)